# python mysqldb delete row

Tags: python, mysql

for some reason, this is bombing out:

```
print tbl,record
statmt="DELETE FROM '%s' WHERE email LIKE '%s'" %(tbl,record)
print statmt
self.cursor.execute(statmt)
```

error:

```
maillist_frogs test@testovich.com
DELETE FROM 'maillist_frogs' WHERE email LIKE 'test@testovich.com'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./compare.py", line 123, in <module>
    main()
  File "./compare.py", line 117, in main
    remove_mailgust = sql_mailgust.removeRow ("maillist_frogs",x)
  File "./compare.py", line 81, in removeRow
    self.cursor.execute(statmt)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''maillist_frogs' WHERE email LIKE 'test@testovich.com'' at line 1")
```

Thanks!! :)

Comment: How about this: `statmt="DELETE FROM %s WHERE email LIKE '%s'" %(tbl,record)`.

Comment: If I replace self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM %s.email WHERE email LIKE'%s'", tbl,record) then I get TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Answer (score 8):

I was having a similar problem just now.

After further research, I realized I'd forgotten to do a `connection.commit()` after the delete, or, as I found somewhere else, you could just do `cursor.execute("set autocommit = 1")` before doing any other data operations to have them automatically committed right away, if you don't need control over transactions commits.

This could have been the trouble with Cmag's code, though without seeing more, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

```
def removeRow(self,tbl,record):
        """ Remove specific record """
        record = record[0]
        statmt="DELETE FROM %s WHERE email LIKE '%s'" %(tbl,record)
        self.cursor.execute(statmt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

The first one, that is causing your crash, is that you quoted your table name, using regular quotes. If you want to quote table names, you should use backquotes (`).

Second issue, you're 'Not doing it right'. You should not create your queries using string formatting, but instead let Python MySQLdb's `cursor.execute` do it for you, properly.

To do so, try the following:

```
statmt = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE email LIKE %s" 
self.cursor.execute(statmt, (tbl, record))
```

By the way, using string formatting on MySQLdb queries exposes you to SQL injection in case you're going to use your application on the Web or something. You should **not** be using string formatting to create queries.

Comment: fixed: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/528559/, problem now is that the script just loops, no sql records ever get deleted

Comment: But no exceptions get raised? The `cursor.execute` call should return the number of rows deleted, could you print that and check it? Can you double-check that the records do exist in the DB?

Comment: the script at first compares the databases, so yes, records exist for sure

Comment: Well, I tried using your code, it works for me, so your problem is probably somewhere in the DB, did you double-check it? Do you have the necessary permissions? Maybe you could try doing it using MySQL's CLI? Are you sure remove, and x[0] are what you expect? It seems strange that the `cursor.execute` call would return None given that if no rows are deleted, it returns 0, is everything OK there?